# Which sentence is correct? Use of commas and 'and'

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, commas

1. It offers an opportunity to get information, to learn the activities, and to look for a job.
2. It offers an opportunity to get information, learn the activities, and look for a job.
3. It offers an opportunity to get information learn the activities and look for a job

Comment: The last one needs commas, the first and second ones both work and sound natural. So it's just a matter of personal preference with those two.

Comment: Without more context I can't be sure that all three should be: "learn **about the** activities".

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are correct.

First of all, 3 can be ruled out since the use of and in a list of more than two items needs commas.

Structural use of and:

> .... x, y(,) and z.

x, y, and z should be of the same structure/ part of speech, i.e., all nouns, verbs, or even clauses.

Examples:

- Nouns

  > I like to eat apples, mangoes, and oranges.
- Gerunds

  > I like travelling around, solving puzzles, and playing basketball.
- Bare infintives:

  > My every day routine is to eat, work, and sleep.
- To-infinitives:

  > My everyday routine is to eat, to work, and to sleep.
- Adjectives

  > This student is clever, humourous, and humble.

1 is OK as described in the to-infinitives case, while 2 is similar to the bare infinitives case.

Hope this helps!

---

*Sidenotes:*

*1. We usually use the preposition 'about' or 'through' after learn*

*2. The second comma in the examples above can be omitted. Some people, like me, use it for clarity. It is called the Oxford comma.*